# How to print .xlsx format in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qprinter

This is my code:

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
printer.setPageMargins (15,15,15,15,QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer.setFullPage(false);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
if(dialog.exec() != dialog.Accepted) {
    return;
}

QPainter painter(&printer);
painter.setFont(QFont("Tahoma",15));
QFile file;
file.setFileName("D:/cedvel2017.xlsx");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
char line[1024];
int lineNum = 0;
while(file.readLine(line,1024)>0) {
    lineNum++;
    QString str(line);
    painter.drawText(10,40*lineNum,str);
    qDebug() << str;
}
file.close();
painter.end();
```

But I have problem with printing. When it prints a table, its data doesn't show in regular format. It has problems with UTF-8 I guess. You can see the hard printed copy [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd1F1.jpg).

How can I solve it?

Comment: Posting in legendary thread

Comment: What did you expect what would happen? Would you print an image the same way? (Open the file and write binary content to paper?) You need and Excel renderer.

Comment: I expected it was print like Excel Table

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing on the piece of paper is the utf-8 decoded version of the binary file itself. You'll need a Excel-compatible renderer to turn this data into something your can print.

Out of my head:

- If you are on MacOS, you can use `qlmanage` to get a rough preview as a JPG-file. You can probably print that quite easily but you'll have no control over how that preview is created (e.g. only the first sheet will appear).
- On Windows you can `COM`-control an Excel installation and ask it to print that file with all it's sheets.
- You may be able to API-control Libre- or OpenOffice to do the same.

Comment: IIRC, calling `excel.exe -print path/to/Document.xls` will cause excel to just print the damn thing, whatever that means. If you need more control, do some googling on "excel ole api" or "excel com api"